# Can I control what data gets saved with a user's roaming profile?

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-profile, active-directory, roaming-profile

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine running a small corporate domain.  User profiles are stored to a drive array on the server and I'm noticing that the user profiles are very large in some cases ( > 15Gb).  The primary culprit is each users's 'My Documents' folder.

We don't actually have a great need for users to have access to all their assets on multiple machines.  They just need to be able to *log into* multiple machines.  Can I prevent things like appdata, my documents, etc. from being stored with the roaming profile?

Comment: If all they need to do is log in, why are you using a roaming profile at all?

Answer (score 0):

search for ExcludeProfileDirs in the registry!  Or in this case don't use roaming profiles!
Also I'd use folder redirection instead of roaming profiles.